# How to migrate angularjs Upload functionalities to Angular 9

Tags: angularjs, angular

I got the work to migrate my AngularJs code to Angular 9....
And I am stucked with Upload functionalities and they are following:

1. Upload.isFile(obj); //returns boolean to check if the object is file.
2. Upload.dataurltoblob(image Url, "some string") ; //converts a dataurl to blob object.

How to get same functionality in latest Angular version?

Function code:
// First Upload function

$scope.documentDetails = {} ;

$scope.downloadFile = function (){

```
If(! Upload.isFile($scope. documentDetails.imageUrl))
{

    // if true required logic is applied
}
```

}

// Second Upload function

function showImage(){

```
if($scope.documentDetails.contentType == "image/tiff" )
{

    $scope.documentDetails.imageUrl = Upload.dataurltoblob ($scope.documentDetails.imageUrl," tiff") ;
}
```

}

Comment: please post those functions

Comment: Posted the functions... :)

Answer (score 0):

Every `$scope` property that is referenced in the html should be a `public` member so it could be referenced from angular component html.

So:

```
public documentDetails; // Should be public if referenced in the html

public downloadFile() {
   If(!Upload.isFile(this.documentDetails.imageUrl))
   {
      // if true required logic is applied
   }
}

public showImage() {
   if(this.documentDetails.contentType == "image/tiff" )
   {

       this.documentDetails.imageUrl = Upload.dataurltoblob (this.documentDetails.imageUrl," tiff") ;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Yes,that I know... But I need to find the alternative of Upload function in Angular 9. Any advice for that.

Comment: Where Upload is coming from? Can you post it please? Is it 3rd party or your code?

Comment: //inject angular file upload directive.
angular.module('myApp', ['ngFileUpload']);

var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', 'Upload', function($scope, Upload) {.... // Upload function is then used as required....}

Comment: Does this work for you https://morioh.com/p/eb16dada527d?

Comment: I have already gone through this document neither the "FileUploader" nor "FileSelectDirective" of ng2-file-upload  directive provides any method which serves as an alternative for "Upload.isFile()" and "Upload.dataurltoblob()"